SSO in ingress nginx with Github not working as expected
I am using this example to set up SSO for my ingress controller:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --provider=github
        - --email-domain=*
        - --upstream=file:///dev/null
        - --http-address=0.0.0.0:4180
        # Register a new application
        # https://github.com/settings/applications/new
        env:
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID
          value: <Client ID>
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET
          value: <Client Secret>
        # docker run -ti --rm python:3-alpine python -c 'import secrets,base64; print(base64.b64encode(base64.b64encode(secrets.token_bytes(16))));'
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET
          value: SECRET
        # Recommended: remove email-domain=* in args and set an allowlist
        # - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_GITHUB_USERS
        #   value: alice,bob
        image: quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: oauth2-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4180
          protocol: TCP

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 4180
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4180
  selector:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: __INGRESS_HOST__
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /oauth2
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: oauth2-proxy
            port:
              number: 4180
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - __INGRESS_HOST__
    secretName: __INGRESS_SECRET__

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
  name: external-auth-oauth2
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: __INGRESS_HOST__
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port:
              number: 80

and I am facing two issues:

If I used the same hostname for both ingresses, one ingress will lose all IPs.

If I switch to a different hostname, the SSO works, but I can still access the service even when I am not logged in.


I tried with two public hosts on cloudflare but can still access the service with or without login.
My system is an on-premise which is running on metallb ARP mode.
